# Java ClassCastException: cannot be cast to itself

Tags: java, casting

I'm decoding some multi-part e-mail messages, and as part of the process I call this:

`BASE64DecoderStream b64ds = (BASE64DecoderStream) part.getContent();`

(`part` is an instance of javax.mail.Part)

I'm getting this error:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream`

Notice that the two classes are **identical** in the error.
  Why does the casting fail?

Comment: F.e. class owned by different classloader is not the same class

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
BASE64DecoderStream b64ds = part.getContent();
```